# AC coupling of relay driving circuit - Driving relays using PWM

Tags: relay, pwm, coupling

I have designed this circuit and math calculation works but looking back now I feel the cap is too small may be I am making any mistake here? Can some one explain how to chose the capacitor for AC coupling the relay driver.
Please do not engage in to side discussion, why I would want to drive relay with AC signal.

[image]

Note: RLY_RUN is PWM signal, which is changed to 5V level by U63 and 100R & 47 nF acts as AC coupling to drive the U23 MOSFET. the relay used here is 24 V DC relay .

I couldn't find any design or application note on this anywhere on the Internet  so far.

Comment: Probably, your math is bad.

Comment: probably you have to implement a push-pull configuration to energise the coil

Comment: 1) "math calculation works": Would you post your calculation?  
2) Why does it need to be AC coupled, DC coupling should work as well? 
3) What is the PWM period and duty?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič , Explain what you mean by this.

Comment: Is that you were doing wrong calculation, this circuit won't work as is.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič can you explain me the correct math , or you just bully people around with what cooks in your mind .

Answer (score 1):

As Gino says in the comments, you need a push-pull drive. You’ve chosen a 74AHCT17 which is open collector/drain. It will only pull the signal low. Your circuit wont work as there’s no means to charge the capacitor. Adding a pullup resistor will help but may cause the relay to glitch on power up. Or chose a different device for U63.

Comment: 74AHCT17APWJ is non inverting buffer , this buffer is driven at 20Khz , 80% Duty . 5V is output of this buffer. The PWM is passed through the capacitor and output of capacitor is bipolar waveform (i.e between +/- 2.5V). For +ve 2.5V it will trigger NUD3124 as NUD3124 has 2V threshold. now relay will turn ON. For PWM OFF duration the cap voltage is -2.5V , which will be clamped to ground by NUD diodes and on driver side, the 100ohm will take the potential difference.

Comment: Ah, the ahct17 is a weird ass part. The 7417 is an open collector buffer. Ok, what measurements have you done?

Comment: Lol.. what!...Open collector buffer... you cracked me up buddy.  Why you keep referring this part as open collector. there is the part , take a look at datasheet.. for the last time open collector has nothing to with it.

Comment: Thats what I acknowledged. What measurements have you done?

Comment: Yes this circuit is tested and in use. I have done measurements at Vds of mosfet , Relay operation was tested. My question is about long term reliability of this circuit